# *ngIf with Fixed Date

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

How do I compare a variable date with a fixed date in an *ngIf call.

In my .ts file, I have:

```
  public _dateFrom: Date;
```

Then, I've tried this and it produced a compiler error:

```
<div *ngIf="_dateFrom >= (new Date('12/1/2010'))">        
</div>
```

Also tried this with the same problem:

```
<div *ngIf="_dateFrom >= (new Date(2010,12,1))">        
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular template doesn't allow creating variables. You could try to create a function in the controller and return the comparison.

Two more things to notice:

1. Months are zero indexed in Javascript. So you might have actually meant `(2010, 11, 1)` for 1st December 2010.
2. It is better to compare the value of [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method instead of directly comparing the date objects.

Try the following

Controller

```js
isOldThan(year: number, month: number, date: number) {
  return this._dateFrom.getTime() >= (new Date(year, month, date)).getTime();
}
```

Template

```html
<div *ngIf="isOldThan(2010, 11, 1)">        
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think calling isOldThan on the template is a good idea,  It might cause performance issues.

Comment: It is true the function will be called multiple times due to change detection. Likewise it will be triggered multiple times in expressions `{{ isOldThan(2010, 11, 1) }}` and in `*ngFor` directive `let item of someFunction()`. But at the moment I couldn't think of another way to check a condition against a _fixed_ constant in the controller. May be a custom version of `*ngIf` directive.

Comment: it's not a problem of changeDetection. ChangeDetection it's triggered because we want that. If you don't want the component to be triggered everytime, just change the detection in onPush.

Comment: You could create a custom structural directive or calculate a property on the component in the ngOnChanges if you want to avoid calling a method directly from the template.